# How to get a raw pointer *mut f32 from a rust vector Vec<[f32;3]>?

Tags: c, pointers, rust, ffi

I'm new to rust and I'm struggling to connect my rust code with a C library.
The library expects a raw pointer `*f32` to the memory buffer of size 3*N. In rust code I have an array `Vec<[f32;3]>` of size N.
How can I get a raw pointer of type `*mut f32` from this array?

```
let coords: Vec<[f32;3]> = vec![[0.0,0.0,0.0]; N];
// Call a wrapper of C function expecting a raw pointer *mut f32
wrapped_c_function(coords.????, 3*N);
```

I tried `coords.as_mut_ptr()` but it doesn't work because of the type mismatch:

```
mismatched types
expected raw pointer `*mut f32`
   found raw pointer `*mut [f32; 3]`
```

So I need to "flatten" the data to be treated as a pointer to flat f32 buffer.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arrays are flat in memory, the layout of a pointer `*mut f32` to `N * 3` elements is the same as of `*mut [f32; 3]` of `N` elements. Therefore, you can just [`cast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast-1):

```rust
let ptr: *mut f32 = coords.as_mut_ptr().cast::<f32>();
```

Comment: OT: Does ```[f32; 3]``` mean an array of ```3``` 4-byte floating point numbers?

Comment: @Haris Yes. `float[3]` in C (though not exactly, because C arrays are pointers).

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious in fact. Thank you!